# Regular Expr when not all matches are present

Tags: regex

I am wondering if there is a way to handle situations where there is not always a match for all groups. In my case i have a text which i am trying to parse but there is an element that does not have some elements so my pattern skips over some data which is not desired.

```
<FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>1260 CORONA POINTE STE 120<br/>CORONA, CA  92879<br/><br/></font></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td></td><td><FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>2124 MAIN ST STE 100<br/>HUNTINGTON BEACH, CA  92648<br/><A HREF = "pplinfo.asp?License_id=00610922">00610922</A> Miller, David S  - Branch/Division Manager<br><br/><br/></font></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td></td><td>
```

the pattern i am using is below and will only create one match

```
/<FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>(.*?)<br\/>(.*?)<br\/>.*?License_id=(\d*?)">.*?<\/A>(.*?)<br>/gm
```

if i use this pattern i will have 2 matches

```
/<FONT FACE="Arial,Helvetica" size=2>(.*?)<br\/>(.*?)<br\/>/gm
```

In my case the source of problem is that i am trying to match the License_id= as well as the name which is not avail in the first match.
so what i am looking for is a way to return an empty match or something so if a match is not present it will not offset my data
I am using JavaScript / NodeJS

Comment: Please consider boiling this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The sample data you’re showing is quite long and complicated.

Comment: Oh yes, and indicate what language or tool you’re using. Regex specifications vary quite a lot from one language to another.

Comment: Updated question and made code smaller and provided additional info

Comment: If you're using JavaScript, why not just use something like `.getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: I want to stick with Regex and hope that i can find a fix other then going to find all matches and the loop over them to break them down further

Comment: So your record goes from one font tag to the next font tag ?

Comment: Trying using a tool like https://regexr.com/ to let you play around with your expression comparing against real data and get immediate feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This way is done in 2 or 3 steps.***

- It first gets the record, from a *FONT* tag to just before the next *FONT* tag.
- Then it removes all the tags from the record by replacing with a newline.
  That makes each content section that is left, a separate line.
- It then splits the string on newline to get into an array.

*The last 2 things are optional, take your pick.*

```js
var html = "<FONT FACE=\"Arial,Helvetica\" size=2>1260 CORONA POINTE STE 120<br/>CORONA, CA  92879<br/><br/></font></td></tr><tr valign=\"top\"><td></td><td><FONT FACE=\"Arial,Helvetica\" size=2>2124 MAIN ST STE 100<br/>HUNTINGTON BEACH, CA  92648<br/><A HREF = \"pplinfo.asp?License_id=00610922\">00610922</A> Miller, David S  - Branch/Division Manager<br><br/><br/></font></td></tr><tr valign=\"top\"><td></td><td>";

var rxTag = new RegExp( "(?:\\s*<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\\s*>)[\\S\\s]*?</\\1\\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\\w:]+\\s*/?)|(?:[\\w:]+\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\\s*/?)|\\?[\\S\\s]*?\\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:\\[CDATA\\[[\\S\\s]*?\\]\\])|(?:--[\\S\\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\\S\\s]*?))))>\\s*)+", "g" );

var rxRecord = new RegExp( "<font(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]?)+>(?:(?!<font(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]?)+>)[\\S\\s])*", "gi");

var match;

while ( match = rxRecord.exec( html ) )
{
  var rec = match[0];
  var sData;
  sData = rec.replace( rxTag, "\r\n" );
  sData = sData.trim();
 
  console.log( sData );
  
  var ary = [];
  ary = sData.split( /\r?\n/ );
  console.log( ary );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and i thought along the line and will use this as a blueprint. I just will skip the the making the data a multiline text. Will use 3 steps, get the section, then get matches for each record and then use another pass to brake it into separate records so a missing element will not screw me up